# Select values per specific occurrence from data frame in R

Tags: r, subset

I am stuck with this one:

I have a dataframe with the following properties:

- a variable type (values: "P", "T", "I")
- a variable id (subject id)
- a variable RT (reaction time)

It looks like this:

```
id    type    rt
1     T       333
1     P       912
1     P       467
1     I       773
1     I       123
...
2     P       125
2     I       843
2     T       121
2     P       982
...
```

The order of the variable `type` is random for each subject but each subject has the same amount of each type. What I want is to select the first 2 RT values where `type=="P"` for each participant and then average over occurrences, so that I get a mean RT of all participants for the first occurrence of P, and a mean for the second occurrence of P.

So far, say, 20 participants, I want to extract a total of 20 RTs for the first occurrence and 20 RTs for the second occurrence.

I tried tapply, aggregate, for loop and simple subsetting but these either average "too early" or fail since the order is random for each subject.

Comment: This is not very clear. In the example dataset, do you want the average of `912` and `125` for the first RT?

Comment: @akrun Yes, I want the average of `912` and `125` for the first occurrence and then the average of `476` and `982` for the second occurrence, etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
 library(dplyr)
   df%>%
      group_by(id) %>% 
      filter(type=="P") %>% 
      slice(1:2)%>% 
      mutate(N=row_number()) %>%
      group_by(N) %>% 
      summarise(rt=mean(rt))
     #Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

   # N    rt
   #1 1 518.5
   #2 2 724.5
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
  setDT(df)[type=="P", list(rt=rt[1:2], N=seq_len(.N)), by=id][, 
                                      list(Meanrt=mean(rt)), by=N] 
  #   N Meanrt
  #1: 1  518.5
  #2: 2  724.5
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
  df1 <- subset(df, type=="P")
  df1$indx <- with(df1, ave(rt, id, FUN=seq_along))
  aggregate(rt~indx, df1[df1$indx %in% 1:2,], FUN=mean)
  #  indx    rt
  #1    1 518.5
  #2    2 724.5
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), type = c("T", 
 "P", "P", "I", "I", "P", "I", "T", "P"), rt = c(333L, 912L, 467L, 
 773L, 123L, 125L, 843L, 121L, 982L)), .Names = c("id", "type", 
 "rt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your answer and the many methods you outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got it right, using dplyr:

```
df %>% 
group_by(id, type) %>% 
mutate(occ=1:n()) %>% 
group_by(type, occ) %>% 
summarise(av=mean(rt)) %>%
filter(type=="P")

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: type

  type occ    av
1    P   1 518.5
2    P   2 724.5
```